# Display .R script in output of .Rmd file

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

Is it possible to include or display an .r script in the output of .rmd file?
Important - just want to display the .r file!
Tried source(filename.r); source does not display it.
Any ideas?

````
**knitr Global Options**   

```{r echo=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy=FALSE, fig.path='figures/')
```

**Load Libraries**   

```{r echo=TRUE}
library(dplyr)
```

```{r echo=TRUE, include=TRUE}
source("external.R")
# the complete source code of the .r file should be displayed here
# possible?
```
````

What would be the use-case for such a requirement?
Creating .Rmd helps with documentation. In fact all my documentation is created using .Rmd.
There are .R scripts which take a long time to run (processing large data). In such a case working with .Rmd is not practical. Prefer to work with .R scripts.
If the source code of the .R can be "included & displayed" in the .Rmd would be wonderful for documentation purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For this particular case, there is a simple solution. That is, you can assign source code to the chunk option `code`, then **knitr** will just take your source code as if it were written in the code chunk, e.g.

````
```{r, code = readLines('external.R')}
```
````

Alternatively and equivalently, you can use the `file` option:

````
```{r, file = 'external.R'}
```
````

Comment: Nice. I should've known to just wait until you came along with the perfectly elegant solution :)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Oh no, please keep up your momentum :) Thanks! I'm answering this one just because it is not a widely known feature, and I was glad that I found a use case.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio That is just a basic subsetting question. You can `readLines('external.R')[c(lines, you, want, to, use)]`.

Comment: Yihui, does this solution only prints the script code or does it execute it as well? I've been getting some strange issues here.

Comment: You can choose to execute it or not by `eval = TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Been a while since this was posted.  Is there a way to automate this in Rmd when I want to output a few different scripts?  As in, I want to define a function to print the two lines of code here, where the only thing that changes is the filename.