# Can I wrap markdown and R code chunks into a function?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have text files that I want to display in an RMD document as unevaluated code, and hidden behind a code-folding button.  I'm using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29760070/3790973) and [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755037/how-to-add-code-folding-to-output-chunks-in-rmarkdown-html-documents) to include my text files, but I want to automate the process of pulling these files in.

This solution works, but instead of having dozens of lines like this:

````
    # Create an External Script
    writeLines("# A Sample R Script", "external.R")

    # Then include the R script in an Rmd document
    <details>
    ```{r, code = readLines('external.R')}
    ```
    </details>
    <details>
    ```{r, code = readLines('external.R')}
    ```
    </details>
    <details>
    ```{r, code = readLines('external.R')}
    ```
    </details>
````

Is there a way I can use `cat` or `paste` to wrap this into a function, where the only thing that is changing is the external script that I'm using?

````
# Define the function
my_fn <- function(script_path){
  paste0("<details>\n```{r, code = readLines(", script_path, ")}\n```\</details>"
}

# Then use in Rmd
my_fn("external.R")
my_fn("external.R")
my_fn("external.R")
````

Comment: After much trial and error, I'm finding that R Markdown really does not like putting ``` in quotes, and I can't find a way around that.  I can get the code chunk to appear by replacing ` with \x60, but the code is not evaluated in RMD.

Comment: This would be really helpful to create a shortcut function for inserting figures, where most of the options lie within the { } brackets, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63665513/how-to-add-subfigure-in-r-markdown-bookdown